# Will gevent speed up pymongo connection

Tags: nginx, pymongo, uwsgi, gevent

I am using bottle with `pymongo`. My server is `nginx` and `uwsgi`.

Will gevent make my pymongo run async(What I mean multithread) by just using the code below?

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_socket()
```

My reference:

http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/gevent.html

---

Update:

I have updated the uwsgi.ini:

```
[uwsgi]
plugins=python
socket=/tmp/uwsgi.myapp.socketpython
path=/var/www/myapp
gevent = 100
```

Am I doing it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to enable gevent mode in uWSGI too

http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Gevent.html

then use monkey.patch_all() instead of monkey.patch_socket() as uWSGI is a native gevent application and do not use its monkey patch features by default.